# Undefined is not an object (evaluating'_this._ageinput = _ref2')

Tags: forms, react-native

I am trying to create a registration form for my mobile app thanks to a tutorial and I get an error that I do not understand ...

unfortunately when I try this following code : I get "Undefined is not an object (evaluating'_this._ageinput = _ref2')" Can you help me find what's wrong ? Do you know what it means ? Thanks a lot.

Could you help me find the origin of this problem? Or at least give me a lead to follow?

Thank you very much for your time and help.

[image]

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import {
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  View,
  Text,
  Image,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  Keyboard,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ScrollView,
} from 'react-native';
import Loader from '../../src/components/Loader';
import styles from '../../assets/styles';

const Signup = props => {
  let [userName, setUserName] = useState('');
  let [userEmail, setUserEmail] = useState('');
  let [userAge, setUserAge] = useState('');
  let [userAddress, setUserAddress] = useState('');
  let [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  let [errortext, setErrortext] = useState('');
  let [isRegistraionSuccess, setIsRegistraionSuccess] = useState(false);

  const handleSubmitButton = () => {
    setErrortext('');
    if (!userName) {
      alert('Please fill Name');
      return;
    }
    if (!userEmail) {
      alert('Please fill Email');
      return;
    }
    if (!userAge) {
      alert('Please fill Age');
      return;
    }
    if (!userAddress) {
      alert('Please fill Address');
      return;
    }
    //Show Loader
    setLoading(true);
    var dataToSend = {
      user_name: userName,
      user_email: userEmail,
      user_age: userAge,
      user_address: userAddress,
    };
    var formBody = [];
    for (var key in dataToSend) {
      var encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(key);
      var encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(dataToSend[key]);
      formBody.push(encodedKey + '=' + encodedValue);
    }
    formBody = formBody.join('&');

    fetch('https://aboutreact.herokuapp.com/register.php', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formBody,
      headers: {
        //Header Defination
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
      },
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        //Hide Loader
        setLoading(false);
        console.log(responseJson);
        // If server response message same as Data Matched
        if (responseJson.status == 1) {
          setIsRegistraionSuccess(true);
          console.log('Registration Successful. Please Login to proceed');
        } else {
          setErrortext('Registration Unsuccessful');
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        //Hide Loader
        setLoading(false);
        console.error(error);
      });
  };
  if (isRegistraionSuccess) {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: '#307ecc',
          justifyContent: 'center',
        }}>
        <Image
          source={require('../../assets/images/authentication.png')}
          style={{ height: 150, resizeMode: 'contain', alignSelf: 'center' }}
        />
        <Text style={styles.successTextStyle}>Registration Successful.</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.buttonStyle}
          activeOpacity={0.5}
          onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Login')}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonTextStyle}>Login Now</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#F78400' }}>
      <Loader loading={loading} />
      <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled">
        <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <Image
            source={require('../../assets/images/cash-register.png')}
            style={{
              width: '50%',
              height: 100,
              resizeMode: 'contain',
              margin: 30,
            }}
          />
        </View>
        <KeyboardAvoidingView enabled>
          <View style={styles.SectionStyle}>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.inputStyle}
              onChangeText={UserName => setUserName(UserName)}
              underlineColorAndroid="#FFFFFF"
              placeholder="Enter Name"
              placeholderTextColor="#F6F6F7"
              autoCapitalize="sentences"
              returnKeyType="next"
              onSubmitEditing={() =>
                this._emailinput && this._emailinput.focus()
              }
              blurOnSubmit={false}
            />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.SectionStyle}>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.inputStyle}
              onChangeText={UserEmail => setUserEmail(UserEmail)}
              underlineColorAndroid="#F6F6F7"
              placeholder="Enter Email"
              placeholderTextColor="#F6F6F7"
              keyboardType="email-address"
              ref={ref => {
                this._emailinput = ref;
              }}
              returnKeyType="next"
              onSubmitEditing={() => this._ageinput && this._ageinput.focus()}
              blurOnSubmit={false}
            />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.SectionStyle}>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.inputStyle}
              onChangeText={UserAge => setUserAge(UserAge)}
              underlineColorAndroid="#F6F6F7"
              placeholder="Enter Age"
              placeholderTextColor="#F6F6F7"
              keyboardType="numeric"
              ref={ref => {
                this._ageinput = ref;
              }}
              onSubmitEditing={() =>
                this._addressinput && this._addressinput.focus()
              }
              blurOnSubmit={false}
            />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.SectionStyle}>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.inputStyle}
              onChangeText={UserAddress => setUserAddress(UserAddress)}
              underlineColorAndroid="#FFFFFF"
              placeholder="Enter Address"
              placeholderTextColor="#F6F6F7"
              autoCapitalize="sentences"
              ref={ref => {
                this._addressinput = ref;
              }}
              returnKeyType="next"
              onSubmitEditing={Keyboard.dismiss}
              blurOnSubmit={false}
            />
          </View>
          {errortext != '' ? (
            <Text style={styles.errorTextStyle}> {errortext} </Text>
          ) : null}
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.buttonStyle}
            activeOpacity={0.5}
            onPress={handleSubmitButton}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonTextStyle}>REGISTER</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};
export default Signup;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a functional component so you shouldnt use 'this'

if you remove the 'this' and change like below it will work

```
           <TextInput
              style={styles.inputStyle}
              onChangeText={UserAge => setUserAge(UserAge)}
              underlineColorAndroid="#F6F6F7"
              placeholder="Enter Age"
              placeholderTextColor="#F6F6F7"
              keyboardType="numeric"
              ref={ref => {
                _ageinput = ref;
              }}
              onSubmitEditing={() =>
                _addressinput && _addressinput.focus()
              }
              blurOnSubmit={false}
            />
```

You will have to change the other inputs like this as well

Comment: You can check the sample from docs here https://reactnative.dev/docs/direct-manipulation#setnativeprops-to-clear-textinput-value

Comment: Thank you so much !!!!! You rock !  I'm really gratefull.